# How can I select and shift data point on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

Hello Everybody I am using Matplotlib and I have a time series data I want to select data with mouse 
and shift it up or down.I would be glad if anybody knows how to do it.
Thanks

Comment: please be more specific.. what do you mean by selecting a data and shifting it? you mean you want to shift data on the processed plot?

Comment: I mean selecting one data point as it is an array element lets say b=[1,2,3] I want to select b[1] which is value 2 on the graph by mouse